# Is it possible to change gcc *default* library search path?

Tags: linux, gcc, path

I know I can modify library search path by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc., but this approach is sometimes lame. I really want to have `/usr/local/lib` in the **default** path, but unfortunately, this seems non-default in GNU/Linux. (I've had quite a few problems with `/usr/local/lib` before, and installing the same libraries in `/usr/lib` instead solved those problems. But I really don't want to mess with `/usr/lib`.)

So, is it possible to modify the **default** library path once and for all? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux, you can edit the entries in **/etc/ld.so.conf**

You can also alter the default search path directly in the compiled executable by passing

`-R /usr/local/lib`

to the C compiler.

You can inspect the compiled-in search path of an executable with:
`readelf -d <file> | grep RPATH`

There's a fuller description [here](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html).

Comment: If you edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` don't forget to run `ldconfig` as root afterwards.

Comment: Ah. Good point. I got caught out by that myself, the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to change library path to a certain binary:

```
patchelf --set-rpath=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib my_binary
```

Comment: I don't know if patchelf is better, but it should be combined with the above answer. It provides a build option to set a RUNPATH.